# Clustering with SVD

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory, laplacian, graph-laplacian

I'm trying to do some clustering on a graph, which is represented by an adjacency matrix $B = A^2$, where $A$ is symmetric.

I tried several methods like taking the eigenvectors of the Laplacian $L = D - B$, or the eigenvectors of the normalized Laplacian $L_{sym} = I_n - D^{-\frac{1}{2}} B D^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, and then doing some K-means clustering, and it worked okay.

However, the embeddings I get are not the best with these methods, and the best results I have are when I compute the truncated SVD of $A = U S V^{\top}$, and then I take $U$ for my embeddings. $U S^{\alpha}$ for some values of alpha (between 0 and 0.5) actually gives me extremely good results.

However, I can't find any mathematical explanation of why this works, because basically taking $U$ is equivalent to taking the first eigenvectors of $B$ (since $B \approx U S^2 U^\top$), but I don't understand how it gives me good results.

I can't find any theory on this, any ideas?

Comment: Are there any conditions on $A$ other than symmetric? Given that $B$ is the adjacency matrix and $B=A^2$, the graph would be allowed to have loops and/or multiple edges, correct?

Comment: Yes, there are loops, multiple edges. The only restriction is that A is symmetric, values of A are positive, and the graph is connected. Moreover, A is sparse (about 99.5% sparse, with A of size 100,000 square)

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that the exponents $1/2$ instead of $-1/2$ for the symmetric Laplacian was just a typo.  If not that could partially explain why the clustering was only okay.  In any case, I don't have a good explanation right now for why you're getting better results.  What I want to do, but can't find the time for right now, is read through the justification of the technique for the Laplacian matrices and see if there's anything in the argument that carries over to the adjacency matrix case.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the $-1/2$ which was indeed a typo. I read this proof on the Laplacian, and the method makes sense since it's finding vectors that minimizes the energy function of the graph. But there is no reason at all that the eigenvectors of $A^2$ work as well...